# Sharing components between nested React.js apps

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, symlink, create-react-app

I have a React.js app that was bootstrapped with create-react-app that is nested inside another React.js app that was bootstrapped the same way, the project directory looks like this:

```
.
+-- admin
|   +-- node_modules
|   +-- public
|   +-- src
|       +-- pages
|       |   +-- MyFavoriteIconsInTheWorld.js
|       +-- styles
|       +-- App.js
|       +-- Index.js
|       +-- package.json
+-- ansible
+-- bin
+-- node_modules
+-- public
+-- src
|   +-- pages
|   +-- components
|   |   +-- Icons
|   +-- styles
|   +-- App.js
|   +-- Index.js
|   +-- package.json
+-- config
|   +-- jest
|   +-- webpack
|       +-- webpack.admin.dev.js
|       +-- webpack.admin.prod.js
|       +-- webpack.config.dev.js
|       +-- webpack.config.dev.js
```

The Icons folder inside of the main React.js app has several components that I need to use import in admin/src/pages/MyFavoriteIconsInTheWorld.js
I tried to do this by adding this alias to my webpack.admin.dev.js:

```
    alias: {
        "%GLOBAL_STORE%": path.resolve(paths.appSrc, './global/store'),
        "%COMPONENTS%": path.resolve(__dirname, '../../src/components'),
    },
```

and then adding this to MyFavoriteIconsInTheWorld.js:

```
    import { AddIcon, Spinner } from '%COMPONENTS%/Icons';
```

but I got this error:

```
Failed to compile.

./admin/src/pages/PromosMyFavoriteIconsInTheWorld.js
Module not found: You attempted to import 
/Users/sclancy/dev/companyNameHere/src/components/Icons which falls 
outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ 
are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink 
to it from project's node_modules/.
```

and therein lies the problem, I can't `move it inside src/` and I am not sure how I would go about adding a symlink in this situation. What is the best way to get access to those components? Is there a way to do it without making an NPM package? Is there a webpack config that I can use?

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1492#issuecomment-358170489

Answer (score 0):

The alias solution for craco or rewired *create-react-app* is **[react-app-alias](https://github.com/oklas/react-app-alias)** for systems as: [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco), [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired), [customize-cra](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra)

According docs of mentioned systems replace `react-scripts` with `craco` in *package.json* and configure next:

```
// craco.config.js
const {CracoAliasPlugin} = require('react-app-alias')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoAliasPlugin,
      options: {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Configure aliases in json like this:

```js
// tsconfig.paths.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "example/*": ["example/src/*"],
      "@library/*": ["library/src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

And add this file in `extends` section of main typescript config file:

```js
// tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Regarding creating Symlinks in Webpack:
[Symlinks in Github Issues (Webpack)](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1643)

As for accessing the original webpack, I would eject it as soon as possible...Create React App is there to help you build the basics, but not being able to modify the webpack is always a pain.

Comment: I went ahead and ejected, I also removed the ModuleScopePlugin to allow the file paths I need, now I have this error `Module parse failed: /Users/sclancy/dev/companyNameHere/src/components/Icons/LeftChevron.js Unexpected token (6:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

Comment: You'll have to grab that loader. I'll have a look at the create react app eject file for you.